# Output from two processes on shell (Python,Linux)

Tags: python, linux, shell

My python script executes program that sends its output on shell.
However, script should simultaneously execute its own commands which also have its output on shell. 
Is it possible to do that? Will I see output both from the script and from the process?
Here is the process that has output on shell:

```
s.exe_cmd('./upgrade')
```

So, will I be able to write

```
print "my output..."
```

and see it on shell to?

Comment: Why not try it and find out?

Comment: "sends its output on shell" makes absolutely no sense.  The shell is just a process.  Your interactive shell has its stdout associated with a tty, and all of its children inherit that file descriptor unless redirected.  If two processes both write data to a tty, the tty will display the data in the order it is received.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using `subprocess` - it will print both on the console.

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen("sleep 1 && echo from inside subprocess",
                     shell=True)
print("will print asynchronously")
p.wait()
```

This is an example program that you can try out